# how would I compare the values to that of the user's, and then check if it is blacklisted

Tags: javascript

I am working on something to blacklist unwanted locations with the location service. Here is my current code:

How can I compare the values?

MAIN SCRIPT:

```
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // Locate position
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayPosition, errorFunction

);
    } else {
        alert('Your device location is not approved.');
    }

    // Success callback function
    function displayPosition(pos) {
        var mylat = pos.coords.latitude;
        var mylong = pos.coords.longitude;
        var thediv = document.getElementById('locationinfo');
      alert('Your HWID is compliant of ProtoProt regulations.');
    }
      function errorFunction(pos) {
        alert('Error: (PROTOPROT_POS_DENIED). We only use your HWID for checking compliance. Enable location to enter.');
        }
```

VALUES DICTIONARY:

```
blacklisted_areas = {
  'area 51' : [w, y], // Replace w y with the floats of long and lat
  'pink unicorn zoo' : [w, y], // same
  // etc.
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an array containing both the latitude and longitude in your `displayPosition` function, and then compare this array against the keys in `blacklisted_areas`.

This can be done with the following (in ES6):

```js
blacklisted_areas = {
  'area 51': [1, 2], // Replace w y with the floats of long and lat
  'pink unicorn zoo': [1, 2], // same
};

function displayPosition(pos) {
  var mylat = 1;
  var mylong = 2;
  return [mylat, mylong];
}

var blacklisted = false;

for (let x of Object.values(blacklisted_areas)) {
  if (displayPosition()[0] === x[0] && displayPosition()[1] === x[1]) {
    blacklisted = true;
  }
}

console.log(blacklisted);
```

In the above code, the variable `blacklisted` will return `true` if the location is blacklisted, and `false` if the variable is not blacklisted. From here, you can adapt to suit.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: However I am having some trouble with putting the script together, because when I test for "blacklisted" as true, before it even requests the location of the user, it gives the success msg.

Comment: I've slightly modified the code, and it should now return correctly. Note that the `console.log(blacklisted)` in my example is not inside a function or callback, so will output as soon as that block of code is reached. As you're working with geolocation, I'm **assuming** you're polling a service, which takes time to execute. You may need to chain the entire `for` loop and output from my example to the callback from this service, so that it actually gets the location before it checks if it's blacklisted ;)

Comment: And the geolocation is browser-based